# Como o ajax faz para identificar classes

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Tenho a seguinte aplicação:

```
        function atualizarPrdutos(categoria){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "teste.aspx/InsertData",
                data: JSON.stringify({categoria:categoria }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (produtos) {
                var prods = produtos.d;
                    $.each(prods, function (index, prod) {
                        alert(prods.titulo);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

E no arquivo teste.aspx.cs:

```
Public Class Produto
    Public id As Integer = 0
    Public titulo As String = ""
    Public imagem As String = ""
    Public valor As Decimal = 0
End Class

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function InsertData(categoria As String) As List(Of Produto)        
        MyConnection.Open()
        Dim comando2 As New OleDbCommand
        comando2.Connection = MyConnection
        comando2.CommandText = "SELECT id, nome, valor, FotoVitrine from loja_produtos WHERE Menu=" + categoria
        Dim reader2 As OleDbDataReader = comando2.ExecuteReader()

        Dim list As New List(Of Produto)()
        While reader2.Read
            Dim produto As New Produto()
            produto.id = reader2.Item("id")
            produto.titulo = reader2.Item("nome")
            produto.valor = reader2.Item("valor")
            produto.imagem = reader2.Item("FotoVitrine")
            list.Add(produto)
        End While
        Return list
    End Function
```

Minha pergunta é: Como que o ajax consegue identificar que a lista tem as propriedades .titulo por exemplo.

Comment: Quer saber como saber no javascript se a propriedade existe ou como funciona internamente o ajax e como ele lê/trata os dados recebidos do servidor? Se fôr o caso da primeira opção, pode colocar na pergunta o retorno que dá na consola do browser de `console.log(produtos);` dentro da função success do ajax?

Comment: Quero saber como ele funciona internamente, como ele conversa com o servidor e lê/trata os dados.

Comment: Vou apenas comentar por não ter certeza absoluta. Na minha opinião "ele", AJAX, não sabe. AJAX é a técnica em si e apesar de ter vários recursos, não é responsabilidade dele conhecer uma estrutura construída pela aplicação *server-side*. JSON, a grosso modo, é um array associativo. E pelo que percebo, JS é bem flexível quanto esse tipo de "falha de estrutura". Em termos práticos e diretos, se o dado existe, trabalha. Se não trabalha apenas pra dizer que não existe (*undefined*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você fizer um post para a URL `teste.aspx/InsertData` contendo o corpo `{categoria:categoria }` e cabeçalhos da requisição (por exemplo, com o cliente [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/)), receberá uma resposta em formato [JSON](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Quem faz essa conversão do seu objeto VB.NET para JSON é seu próprio *web service* (server side). Nesse caso do VB.NET, ele fará uma serialização automática da lista de produtos para formato JSON.

O lado cliente por sua vez receberá a resposta desse *request* contendo todo o corpo em formato JSON e o disponibilizará no parâmetro da função de sucesso (nesse caso `produtos`, mas poderia ser qualquer nome).

As atribuições do Ajax (request em background) terminam aí.

Daí para frente será responsabilidade da sua função de *callback* JavaScript fazer algo com a resposta recebida do servidor. No caso, como bem colocado pelo [Bruno Augusto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17660/como-o-ajax-faz-para-identificar-classes#comment33409_17660) nada é feito para tratar a resposta além do *parse* do conteúdo JSON em objetos JavaScript (o cliente do jQuery sabe que o tipo é JSON pois você informou isso no parâmetro `dataType`, caso o tipo não tivesse sido informado o jQuery tentaria inferir o tipo através do MIME Type da resposta).

Nesse momento você já poderá visualizar toda a árvore de objetos da resposta (e.g., com um *debugger*).

A sua função de *callback* possui conhecimento implícito sobre o *schema* JSON (ou seja, você, desenvolvedor, sabe que `objeto.d[] <-> List (Of Produto)`) conforme o que foi serializado no *server side*) e, sabendo disso, apenas itera os objetos dentro desse *array* `d` exibindo os títulos.